# How to remove substring from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am a newbie with XSLT. I have an XML file which has many values for a tag

```
<submitTime>2016-06-09T18:27:56+0000</submitTime>
<submitTime>2016-06-09T18:13:10+0000</submitTime>
.......
```

I want to convert this **submitTime** date format into this format(YYYY-MM-DD):

```
<submitTime>2016-06-09</submitTime>
```

How can I remove the time from date format? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this help? http://zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_substring.html

Comment: do you have to use xslt? is it a requirement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `submitTime` value is so consistent, you can simply use [`substring-before()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-substring-before)...

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'T')"/>
```

Note: The above `xsl:value-of` assumes the context is `submitTime`.